# ArcGIS / Python "select by attribute" LIKE

Tags: python, select, attributes, sql-like, arcgis

ArcGIS 10.1, Python 2.7.2. I have a table of a few variables but 1.7 million cases. I want to select all those cases where (in ArcGIS-interface-speak)

```
"PCD" LIKE 'BT%'
```

So far no luck.

I have been trying variants on this:

```
whereClause = ""PCD" LIKE 'BT%'"
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("sourceSHP", "NEW_SELECTION", whereClause)
```

---

After a lot of trial and error, this works:

```
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("AllPOSTCODES","NEW_SELECTION",""""PCD" LIKE 'BT%' """)
```

Notes:

`"`   single (double) quotes around the source table `"`
`"`   single (double) quotes around the selection `"`
`"""` triple (double) quotes around the `whereclause` `"""`
`"`   single (double) quotes around the variable `"`
`'`   single (single) quotes around the seed string `'`

Comment: Not sure if you are aware of it but there is a [**Geographic Information Systems Stack Exchange**](http://gis.stackexchange.com/) that specialises in questions like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would have worked (with no triple double-quoting) too ...

```
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("AllPOSTCODES","NEW_SELECTION",' "PCD" LIKE ' + " 'BT%' ")
```